# use laravel + vue sanctum to protect Route

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel+ vue sanctum ,i installed sanctum and I try to And try to hide articles for non-registered users and show them only to users who are logged in, but the articles do not appear in either case ,and this message appears in the console:

```
 app.js:197 GET http://localhost:8000/api/articles/ 401 (Unauthorized)
app.js:607 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (app.js:607)
    at settle (app.js:878)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:82)
```

my api.php file is:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
      Route::resource('articles', ArticleController::class);
});
```

my login file is:

```
 <template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-6">
                <form class="form-signin">
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>

                    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.email">{{errors.email[0]}}</span>
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus v-model="form.email">

                    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <span class="text-danger" v-if="errors.password">{{errors.password[0]}}</span>
                    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required v-model="form.password">

                    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <button @click.prevent="loginUser" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>

                    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

    <script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                form:{
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    device_name: 'test'
                },
                errors: []
            }
        },
        methods:{
             loginUser(){
                 axios.post('/api/login', this.form).then(() =>{
                    this.$router.push({ name: 'MainPage' })
                 }).catch((error) =>{
             this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                })
             }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

my login controller is:

```
       <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\User;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required']
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
            return response()->json(Auth::user(), 200);
        }
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' =>['The provided credentials are incorect.']
        ]);


        // $request->validate([
        //     'email' => 'required|email',
        //     'password' => 'required',
        //     'device_name' => 'required',
        // ]);

         $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        // if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        //     throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        //         'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        //     ]);
        // }

        // return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'register done']);

    }
}
```

- Anyone help me protect the route? I have been working for two days to solve this problem

Comment: I recommend you using inertiajs and get rid from authentication flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are going to use sanctum to authenticate your app , you need to

- add the middleware to your kernel
- make axios request with credentials
- make a request to get the csrf :

```js
    axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
        // Login...
    });
```

and in your case i think you are missing the csrf , plus make sure you are under the same domain .

in your case  :

```js
   loginUser(){
          axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
    
             axios.post('/api/login', this.form).then(() =>{
                    this.$router.push({ name: 'MainPage' })
                 }).catch((error) =>{
                      this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                })
         })
   }
```

check out my repo here for a working refrence
[laravel-vue-sanctum-spa boilerplate](https://github.com/HijenHEK/laravel-vue-sanctum-spa)

check out the officials docs
[sanctum docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication)

Comment: Still not working,and the message still appearsوDo you have any other solutions?

Comment: if you have verified with the laravel docs and followed those three points it should work , ofc if its a sanctum problem ,,, did you check the repo ?

if you are sure you did it by the books , go and try fetching articles using postman or insomnia , authenticate get your token and use it as bearer ,, if you where able to fetch posts than you have a sanctum issue and you need to verify again , if it didnt pass than its not even an auth issue which is impossible

Comment: I tried to fetch the data using postman and couldn't get it, so what is the problem now?

Comment: as i said thats impossible , you have to be missing somthing from the docs , its pretty staight forward as the answer ,,

regarding postman
- did you get the token ?
- did you include it as bearer ?

Comment: sorry ,but i need help i dont know from where should i get the token and where should i include it!!!

Comment: i am sure that that answers exactly your question , you cannot use api's and sanctum if you dont know how access tokens and http headers work ,, you need to have some basics regarding those , sanctum is straight forward you can make it work following my answer , but for troubleshooting you need to know the basics ,, visit the links in the answer ,

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add a property to the Article like public.

create a seperate route for public users since public users are not logged on. Since the method you are using now needs a authenticated user.

```php
public function unauthorizedIndex()
{
   return Article::where('public', true)->get()
}
```

I personally would think you still need an access token (bearer token) and use an application like postman to test the API first.

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use ApiResponser;

    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        // attempting login
        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return $this->error(401, 'Credentials not match' );
        }

        // Delete old tokens
        auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();

        // Succesfull login and new token created.
        return $this->success([
            'token' => auth()->user()->createToken('API Token', auth()->user()->abilities())->plainTextToken
        ]);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: where should I write the function unauthorizedIndex()?

Comment: You could use it in a function in the controller or even a separate controller and in the routing you make a group where you put all unauthorized routes. 

Be creative